# What version of org.apache.http.client is in Android 2.2 ? How to use lib in app?

Tags: android

How can I find out what version of HTTPclient is in Android 2.2 ? I think it's important information to have but I didn't see anything in Google's API documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html

Also, after I download Apache's HTTPclient 4.1.3 (or the 4.2 dev beta) how do I make sure my app uses the API calls from the downloaded Apache library instead of Android's built-in HTTPclient API's ?

I think the last time I tried it I got a *lot* of warnings when my app started up about duplicate API's

Thanks !!

Comment: Check this class http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/VersionInfo.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the following code returns an empty versionInfo array on 2.2 using the emulator `final VersionInfo[] httpVersion = VersionInfo.loadVersionInfo(new String[] {"org.apache.http","org.apache.http.client"}, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this official android link , android team supports HttpURLConnection more with compare to DefaultHttpClient of apache ... http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Answer (score 0):

Iam also using Android 2.2 SDK. 
I downloaded most current Apache HTTPclient (httpclient-4.2.1, httpcore-4.2.1, httpmime-4.2.1, apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2) and added the libs to Build path. Then I was able to verify the version being in use by:

Code:

```
VersionInfo vi = VersionInfo.loadVersionInfo("org.apache.http.client",getClass().getClassLoader());  
String version = vi.getRelease();  
Log.d("apache http client version", version);
```

Output:

```
apache http client version 4.2.1
```

Comment: Doesn't this just return the version of the client you downloaded & bundled, as opposed to the OS supplied version?